# Как подключить библиотеку boost::asio в проекте QtCreator qmake

Tags: c++, qtcreator, boost.asio

Windows. MSYS2, MinGW64. В проект в QtCreator с ситемой сборки qmake необходимо подключить библиотеку boost::asio. Заголовные файлы инклюдятся без ошибок. Однако не могу прописать в файле *.pro линковку библиотек при компиляции. В частности `-lboost_system-mt -lws2_32`. При ручной компиляции файлов через командную строку всё проходит успешно (`g++ main.cpp -lboost_system-mt -lws2_32`).

Пишу в .pro:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += \
-lboost_system-mt \
-lws2_32
```

... и получаю поведение, аналогичное отсутствию этих флагов.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось всё просто. Надо использовать параметр `LIBS += ...` для подключения библиотек. Стоитло только написать вопрос и ответ пришел яко инсайт.